# Applying a list of functions to a list of arguments

Tags: r, mapply

*What is the R-idiomatic way of creating a list gotten by applying a list of functions to a list of arguments?*

For example, given a list of functions and a list arguments, equal in number (say, three),

```
fncs <- list(f1, f2, f3)
args <- list(x1, x2, x3)
```

I want to get the list of function values,

```
fnc_vals <- list(f1(x1), f2(x2), f3(x3))
```

In other words, I want to apply a generalized form of the base-R function `mapply` to the lists `fncs` and `args` (which applies a single function to a list of arguments).

This is can easily be done:

```
dapply <- function(args, fncs, ...) {  # "diagonal" apply
    lapply(seq_along(args), function(i) fncs[[i]](args[[i]], ...))
}

fnc_vals <- dapply(args, fncs)
```

However, to my eyes, this is clumsy, because it would be more natural—if possible in R, without contortions—to run pairwise through the functions and arguments to produce the desired function-value list; in **Python**, that would go like this:

```
fncs = [f1, f2, f3]
args = [x1, x2, x3]
fnc_vals = [f(x) for f, x in zip(fncs, args)]
```

*Can this “zippy” construction be implemented in R, as well?*

Comment: Try with `Map` i.e. `Map(function(x,y) x(y), fncs, args)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Map` (which is `mapply` with different defaults) with `do.call`:

```
fncs <- list(mean, median, sd)
args <- list(1:5, 11:13, c(1,1,1,2))
Map(function(f, x) do.call(f, list(x)), fncs, args)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 12
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.5
```

The anonymous function is necessary because `do.call` needs a `list` for its second argument.

Or since you write an anonymous function anyway, you can just use `Map(function(f, x) f(x), fncs, args)` as @akrun points out.